# GFCI WR question

Tags: gfci, weather-resistant

I am installing a couple outlet outside and I noticed a significant price difference between a standard GFCI outlet and the WR GFCI ones.

If I put a GFCI outlet in a weather resistant box why would I need a WR one?

Answer (score 4):

First the NEC defines any receptacle, device or light fixture installed outdoors as a wet or damp location no matter what type of enclosure it is in.

NEC Article 406.4 (D)(6) states that any receptacle installed in a damp or wet location must be labeled suitable for that location (WR).

The difference between a WR and a non WR receptacle is that the WR has additional corrosion protection. Which makes sense even if you install a receptacle in an approved cover, it is still subject to condensation and corrosion.

Hope this helps and stay safe.

Comment: Agree the moisture or dampness outside gets into the electronics of non WR outlets and they fail much faster covered or not.

Answer (score 3):

Weatherproof boxes *aren't*.   Weather resistant GFCIs *aren't*.

My dad taught me a rule about not leaving valuable electronics out in the weather.  I wouldn't put a GFCI anywhere I wouldn't put a smartphone.

Every GFCI device, even the GFCI+receptacle variety, has a feature that lets it protect downline parts of a circuit. Put such a device upline of the outdoor receptacle, and you've provided GFCI protection to the receptacles.

Now you use a plain WR receptacle and a sticker that says "GFCI Protected".